# Translate Arabic?

Tags: arabic, translation

I believe this is arabic, does anyone know what it means?
Thank you in advance for any help.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because translation from another language is off-topic

Answer (score 1):

1: It's not Arabic it's Urdu. It says "ساخت لاہور 1778" which can be translated as "Made in Lahore 1778". I know this because I speak Urdu.

2: Islam Stack Exchange is site for questions and answers about Islam not Arabic language, https://linguistics.stackexchange.com would be better place for this type of questions.

Comment: Thank you! My apologies for not posting in a more appropriate forum.